"He went to New York for two weeks" is correct. But "She drove to Berlin for eight hours" is incorrect. Why? They look the same
CGEL, page 706:

(1) He went to New York for two weeks. — correct

CGEL, page 684:

(2) She drove to Berlin for eight hours. — incorrect

To me, (1) and (2) look the same.
Why is one incorrect, whereas another is correct?
P.S.: CGEL means the textbook "The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language".

What do you mean by "correct"? Idiomatic? More natural? Grammatical? What does CGEL say? What point are they making? Depending on context, for (2) I might say "She drove to Berlin in eight hours”, or "It took her 8 hours to drive to Berlin”. I don't find "She drove to Berlin for eight hours” particularly awkward. "She drove for 8 hours to Berlin" sounds perfectly good.

The question has the premise for being not only useful but also interesting. However, omitting what CGEL says, and why the two examples are mentioned in two different sections / chapters (?) will cause it to flounder.

This looks like one of these edge cases that the CGEL is interested in.  And I'm pretty sure it's discussion is rather nuanced. Not just "correct"/"incorrect".  The examples from CGEL tend to be like this.  It isn't interested in teaching English, but investigating the edge cases, such as why the first indicates a stay of 2 weeks but the second a journey of 8 hours, an why in the second one, the PP would tend to be close to the verb, not in clause-final position

My downvote and my close vote for lack of context.  One would think that by now you would have realized that examining a sentence without context in vitro can be a big waste of time.

Agree with Mari-Lou A. There is nothing wrong with either: Why is she so tired? Answer: Because she drove for 8 hours to X. OR to X for eight hours. It is just the amount of time she drove. CGEL is mistaken here.

Well, you haven't answered my query even though I commented minutes after your last edit. So, I have no choice but vote to close the question for lack of detail. P.S Not my downvote.

@Mari-LouA I didn't give more text from CGEL on purpose because in this thread, I didn't want to accentuate what CGEL writes. I wanted to hear opinions without discussing CGEL's position. As a result, TimR and James Mathai began to find out what CGEL thinks, and for that reason, their answers turned out less useful to me than gnasher729's and James K's. The latter two just said how they themselves see the situation, and so their answers came out really useful to me.

Who says the 2nd sentence is "incorrect", CGEL or you?

How can 1 and 2 be the same? for is for duration. for eight hours is not for two weeks. but you can do many activities for eight hours.

@Mari-LouA CGEL says so. I added the signs of a quote into the post.

If she lives in Potsdam, drives an hour to Berlin, stays eight hours in Berlin and drives an hour back, the second sentence is also correct.
Both sentences refer to the length of the stay, not the length of the journey. If you use the second sentence for a journey taking 8 hours (and then you stay days, weeks or forever) then it is wrong.

I'm not sure I agree with this one.  I think I'd interpret it as an 8 hour drive - an this is probably the nuance that CGEL is drawing out here.

Where does it mention she stopped at Berlin and came back home? This is pure conjecture on your part, you're providing context when none exists. No one, and I want to stress this for the benefit of learners reading this post, would interpret the CGEL's sentence to mean at some point during those eight hours she stayed in Berlin for an unspecified number of hours and then went back home.

The CGEL is rather unlike grammar books for learners.  It is less concerned with the normal way of producing English, and more with the edge cases. "She drove to Berlin for eight hours." is one of those edge cases.
The interesting point about the first sentence is that the duration "two weeks" is understood not to be the length of time of the journey, but the length of time of the stay in New York.  But this interpretation isn't triggered by all verbs of motion. So "She drove to New York for two weeks." is an odd construction.  So it seems there is something about the verb "go" that is different from the verb "drive". It seems to be that there is a conflicting meaning that is possible with "drive", that the duration indicates the time of the journey.  But in that case, the preferred position of the prepositional phrase is right after the verb.  Two weeks seems excessive for a drive, so switching it for "eight hours": "She drove for eight hours". That is grammatical, and you could add "to Berlin".
This sense is not possible with the verb "go"  "She went for eight hours" is usually about the duration of the stay, not the duration of the journey.
In other words, CGEL is noting an interesting (but quite minor) point about the interpretation of durations with the verb "go".
One could add that there are other more natural-sounding ways to express this.  "It took eight hours to drive to Berlin." but CGEL is not really interested in the usual way to say something, but these edge-cases.

OP has asked why Sentence 1 is correct while Sentence 2 is incorrect:

(1) He went to New York for two weeks. — correct..
(2) She drove to Berlin for eight hours. — incorrect

Answer:
Sentence 1 makes complete sense because it implies:
He went to New York for two weeks and then planned to return.
The preposition "for" works here because it refers to the intended duration of the stay.
*Sentence 2" is problematic because:

"To Berlin" specifies the destination.
"For eight hours" indicates the duration of driving, but it does not clarify whether she reached the endpoint (Berlin).
The issue lies with the preposition  ""for",* which suggests continuous action without confirming the outcome.
It implies: She drove for eight hours but didn't necessarily reach Berlin.

Ii. How to Correct Sentence 2:
The sentence can be corrected by emphasizing the completion of the journey:

(3) She drove to Berlin in eight hours.


She drove for eight hours and reached Berlin.
It took her eight hours to drive to Berlin.

III. Key Differences Between Sentence 2 and Sentence 3:
Sentence 2: She drove to Berlin for eight hours.

Does not make it clear whether she reached Berlin.
The phrase "for eight hours" emphasizes the duration of the driving action but not its outcome.

The journey could have been interrupted or incomplete.
Sentence 3: She drove to Berlin in eight hours.

Makes it clear that she reached Berlin.
The phrase "in eight hours" indicates the total time taken to complete the journey.
The preposition "in" highlights the result: the action concluded successfully within that time.

IV. General Difference Between "For" and "In":
"For [duration]" focuses on the time spent performing an action, regardless of the outcome".
In [duration] emphasizes the time taken from to complete a task, with an implicit assumption that the task was finished.

1. I have worked for several different companies over the course of my lifetime. (a) I worked for INT for five years, but (b) now I work for BBS.  (a) means I no longer work for INT.  2. He has worked for ten years as a teaching  assistant. (i) Is he still a TA? (ii) Has he got a different job now? We don't know, only context can clarify. He drives to work every day; the reader will presume that the person always (barring a car accident) reaches their workplace. Who says that "she" didn't arrive at Berlin?

Even if the ambiguity were true, it doesn't mean the sentence is incorrect or ungrammatical.

+1 for the focus on the preposition for in the phrase for eight hours and its sense of continuous action, although there is in my opinion no implicit assumption that the task was completed; rather there is an incongruity between "She drove to Berlin", which does have the aspect of completion,  and "for eight hours", which has the aspect of the ongoing.  The preposition to with simple past verbs of travel and going implies completion: I went to bed or I hiked to the top or I drove to London.

@Mari-LouA For” means I hadn’t reached the end of the shore after I walked for 10 minutes.
“In” means I had crossed the tunnel after walking for 10 minutes.. [Toward a Cognitive Semantics
Cambridge,
by Leonard Talmy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/504610/difference-between-in-and-for#:~:text=%E2%80%9CIn%E2%80%9D%20means%20I%20had%20crossed,after%20walking%20for%2010%20minutes.&text=If%20you%20haven't%20seen,ended%20(as%20RegDwigh%D1%82%20suggests).

In I walked along the shore for 10 minutes… it doesn't end because it's a shore, it's a long stretch of land which could probably be miles long, we don't know. You wouldn't say I walked along the shore in 10 minutes It's different from, say, "I walked for 10 minutes to work." The workplace is a specific location and it usually has an entrance. In any case, in my comment under the OP I suggested "… drove in 8 hours …” and "… took 8 hours to drive …”

@TimR The speaker wants to say that she reached Berlin but there is ambiguity when "for" is used. It doesn't imply that she reached Berlin. But if we use "in" instead it shows completeness. It sounds like this to me.

@JamesMathai  I agree, if the speaker did reach Berlin ("I drove to Berlin")  you can have an adjunct that expresses the length of time taken to drive there ("in eight hours") but not an adjunct that expresses the time the journey is taking ('"for eight hours").

The italicized sentence below is quite unusual, but not outright ungrammatical, certainly not in American English:

Baltimore is only ninety minutes from Philadelphia, but a winter storm hit while we were halfway there. We drove to Baltimore for four hours.

The simple past is a  rhetorical choice there, done for dramatic effect. In normal (non-rhetorical simple account) mode,  the continuous would be used:

We were driving to Baltimore for four hours.

or

It took us four hours to get to Baltimore.

P.S. "We drove to Baltimore" expresses not so much an action-in-time but a mode of travel -- how we traveled.  I imagine it is for that reason that CGEL considers the simple past together with a time phrase expressing duration to be ungrammatical. It would be like saying "We took the train to London for an hour."   To take the train means "to choose the train as mode of transport".

Shall we hire a car?
-- No, let's take the train.

P.P.S. But let's say that a town is normally a two-hour drive away, and today is no exception:

We drove two hours to Albany to see the band.

And finally, "drove to Berlin" can have the sense of a completed journey, and that sense of completion is not compatible with a time phrase expressing the ongoing duration of the journey, which "for eight hours" is.
If the speaker did reach Berlin ("I drove to Berlin")  we can have an adjunct that expresses the length of time taken to drive there ("in eight hours") but not an adjunct that expresses the time the journey is taking ('"for eight hours"), and the corollary is that the inverse is true with the continuous:

We have been driving for eight hours.
We were driving for eight hours.
*We have been driving in eight hours. ungrammatical
*We were driving in eight hours. ungrammatical

The time adjunct with in expresses the time taken to reach the destination or to complete the action.

She ran the 100 meter dash in 10 seconds.
We drove to Baltimore in 90 minutes.

The  time adjunct with for expresses the amount of time that has elapsed so far:

We had been driving for three hours and had not seen a single motel, hotel, or B-n-B with a vacancy sign.
We have been driving for three hours and have not seen a single motel, hotel, or B-n-B with a vacancy sign!


Do you have a copy of the CGEL? Does it really say  that the 2nd sentence is ungrammatical?

@Mari-LouA No, I don't.  Waiting for it to be remaindered :-)

@TimR Here is how it stands in CGEL: (the subhead is titled: "Bounding potential of goal")
With most verbs of motion, including all verbs expressing manner of motion (walk,
drive, swim, fly, etc.) the presence of a goal has the effect of making the clause bounded;
the other change of location elements do not have this effect. Compare:
i She drove to Berlin in /∗for eight hours. [goal]

ii She drove from Bonn in/for eight hours. [source]
iii She walked through the forest for/in eight hours. [path (for) or goal (in)]
In [i] the source, although not expressed, is contextually implied. This means that the
length of the trip is delimited, and driving this distance must be an accomplishment,
must be bounded. We can therefore have a duration adjunct with in but not with for. In [ii] we have a source but no overt goal. A goal can be implied by the
context yielding a bounded process, which sanctions the duration adjunct with in;

but there need not be a contextually derivable goal, and in the absence of an implied goal
the clause expresses an unbounded situation, an activity, which sanctions the adjunct
with for. In [iii] through the forest can express path or goal. In the former case there is
no implication that she reached the end of the forest; here walking along this path is an
unbounded activity, which sanctions for. In the goal interpretation the end of the forest
is reached; the journey was from one end of the forest to the other, which means that it
was bounded, so that in is sanctioned.

@Eugene Thanks for supplying the CGEL context.   I think the final paragraph in my answer ("the sense of a completed journey...is not compatible with...a time phrase expressing ...duration") and CGEL are in agreement.

@TimR To tell the truth, for me as a non-native speaker, the comprehension of "She drove to Berlin for eight hours", on the face of it, would unambiguously be (as you have adduced it in your answer): "She was driving to Berlin for eight hours". But having gone over the CGEL context I have arrived at a conclusion that by "drove" CGEL rather means "arrived in her car", i.e. "She had gotten off from Paris in her car [at the steering wheel] and in eight hours arrived in Berlin". That's why it is "in", not "for". Right?

@Eugene  Please read the final two paragraphs of my answer, starting with "And finally..."  It comes down to understanding the aspectual sense of the prepositional phrases and the aspectual sense of "She drove to Berlin".

@TimR Done. More than pellucid!

@Mari-LouA + TimR. CGEL if need be.

a) "We were driving to Baltimore for/in four hours." — correct with "for", but incorrect with "in" because Progressive means an uncompleted action. b) "We have been driving to Baltimore for/in four hours." — "for" and "in" are both correct because Perfect Progressive can mean both a completed action (in this case, "in" is correct and "for" incorrect) and an uncompleted action (in this case, "for" is correct and "in" incorrect). Did I draw right conclusions from your answer? Thanks.

@Loviii As TimR has laid it down in his answer, "We have been driving in eight hours" is ungrammatical. What makes you think that the Perfect Progressive tense can mean a completed action?        Uses of the present/past perfect progressive tenses: 1. Actions in progress throughout a period (We use the present perfect progressive when we wish to emphasize that an activity has been in progress throughout a period, often with consequences now. Depending on context, this activity may or may not still be in progress at the present time).


The present/past perfect progressive for repeated actions (the perfect progressive forms are often used to show that an action is (or was) frequently repeated). 3. The present/past perfect progressive for drawing conclusions (we use the progressive (seldom the simple) forms to show that we have come to a conclusion based on direct or indirect evidence). - L.G. Alexander "Longman English Grammar"


We have been driving to Baltimore in four hours is (marginally) grammatical only if the context is referring to a trip made on multiple occasions in the recent past; the verb phrase then takes on the meaning "have been completing the journey ... in four hours".  Consider: "Our daughter is a third-year student at Johns Hopkins University in Baltimore. We visit her several times each year. We have been driving to Baltimore in four hours. But they're going to be doing some major roadwork soon, and I expect that will add at least an hour to the trip."

@Loviii The context makes it clear that we are speaking about past trips to Baltimore, not one that is in progress at this very moment. Thus, the only sane meaning available is "we have been completing the trips to Baltimore in four hours", but  there are far more idiomatic ways of expressing the fact. For example, "The drive to Baltimore has been taking us four hours".

The drive to Baltimore refers there to the trip in its entirety.
